# How to enable/disable Commands for Certain Roles (not role) discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-3.8

Ive seen many times when like i have to put a command where only if the person has `x` role then it runs and if it has a `y` role the command doesnt work , also i am having many other issues id like to explain below

1. Enable a command for specific roles:
   if i want that either a person has this role or this role be able to use this command , ive tried

```py
@commands.has_role('Admin')
```

the Thing here goes you can only specify for one role or if your write this twice it need both roles , but i want there be a OR condition which can be like either user has this role OR this role , but i dont seem to find a way like that

2. Blacklist a role from using the whole bot , If someone has a `x` role then it cant use any commands or a paticular command and this should come in precidence before the has role thingy
3. Allow owner to bypass all the Commands and `@commands.has_role` doesnt work on them , they can simply bypass them

i have tried many ways like adding

```
@commands.has_role()
@commands.is_owner()
```

but it takes order of both but isnt there a way to remove it , if there is I would definitely like knowing, and id try to have as short code as possible and btw i sue discord.py 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Question , I see that the answer of Point 1  are in the question itself but for Point 2,3 you will have to change your format , let's go serial wise.
For No. 1
use this setup

```py
@commands.has_any_role("role1","foo",11132312313213) 
# Check if user has any of the roles with the names "role1", "foo", or the role with id 11132312313213
```

For no 2, you can add a `if` function

```
if not roleid in ctx.author.roles:
     # do stuff
```

for 3 use this setup with a one more condition

```
if  rolename in ctx.author.roles or ctx.author.id  == YOUR ID AS INT TYPE:
  # do stuff
else:
  #show error
```

Comment: BRO thanks for the first one That was so useful , but is there any way to blacklist a role? and how should owner bypass every command?

Comment: Hello , I told you about that in point 2 and three , for black listing a role use
```
if not roleid in ctx.author.roles:
     # do stuff
```
and for bypassing owner you can make check wait i will edit my post and give details

Comment: ok thanks for point , but blacklist a role isnt easy because as i told it should have precedence above my commands.has_any_role

Comment: Hello You dont have to use `@commands.has_any_role()` in blacklisting you can simply start your command as `bot.command` or any other decorator